# base64_decode in free WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, base64

I downloaded a free wordpress theme recently from http://freewpthemes.name/. The theme seems to work just fine except that the footer is encoded with base64. I'm not very experienced with code and I'm not sure how to edit this file. Is it possible it is hiding malicious content? I have tried contacting them with no luck. If anyone can provide some direction on my next steps, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin

Edited to include code below:

```
<? eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('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'))); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a harmless Wordpress footer, but to see for yourself you can go to http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/decrypt.php to decode it which results in:

?>                        Copyright ">.               All rights reserved.
               Design by [Luggage](http://www.luggageguides.com), [Barbecue recipes](http://grillbbqrecipes.com/). Download from [Wordpress](http://freewpthemes.name/).

Look familiar?

Comment: Thanks Ron, I wasn't having luck decoding it with other decoders. All looks good to me!